# What does Oliver Queen say in Russian?

Tags: dc, languages, arrowverse, arrow, translation

In *Arrow* Season 2, Episode 6  "Keep Your Enemies Closer", Oliver Queen visits a Russian prison to bust someone out of it.

There, he says something presumably intimidating in Russian, and which makes the gulag guard hand over the keys.

Felicity asks Oliver what he said, but he simply responds with "Please" and a wink.

What was the actual approximate English translation of what Oliver said in this scene? (And what was the Russian, in Cyrillic if possible?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

UPDATED:

> Если вы выстрелите (alternate: их застрелите), мои люди выследят вас и и ваши дети ... станут сиротами
>
> If you shoot (them down), my people will track you down and your children ... will become orphans.

This is said in an incredibly thick English accent, with incorrect intonation, and with poor sound quality. So I can't guarantee it's 100% correct.

Also, Arrow is clearly set in modern time (the car shown is a modern car, at least). Gulag/[ГУЛАГ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%A3%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%93) stopped existing in 1960 (or 1956, depending on details).

Comment: Thanks for the note on gulag. I'll say that that's the term used in the show, they said it was the *worst* gulag, and it's Russian name meant "nightmare".

Comment: ‘Gulag’ has also become a generic term for a prison camp for political prisoners; I have not seen _Arrow_, but they may be using the term in this looser sense.